# What does this Op Amp circuit do in this circuit for a line following robot?

Tags: h-bridge, robotics

I have seen a schematic for a line following robot, but there is something that I can't understand and is shown in the figure below, what is the purpose of the Op Amp circuit? I know that BREAK input in H-Bridge is independent on other pin. Could some one explain what this circuit does?

[image]

Comment: note that the BREAK G is refer to BREAK D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device that looks like an opamp is a [comparator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator), it compares the `REF_I_MAX` input with `ISENSE_G` input. The output is low unless the sense level becomes higher than the reference voltage in which case the `BRAKE_G` output becomes high.

Seems to be a brake mechanism that is activated when the current of the motor exceeds the reference level (for whatever reason).

Comment: does the current of DC motor growing with time ? i think that the amount of current remain constant

Comment: @Hassan The motor uses more current at startup and as it accelerates the current gradually drops. The motor current can also increase where there is a load that resists the spindle rotation and tries to slow the motor down (like an obstacle in the case of the robot).

Comment: That does not make sense at all. An op-amp has very high input impedance - it cannot take current as an input. For a transresistance configuration like this, the current can't be driven directly into the input terminals. Is this perhaps more of a block diagram?

Comment: @sherrellbc . . it would seem that ISENSE_G could be a current sensor with a voltage output.